# Does anyone know of an antivirus that can scan multiple hard drives simultaneously?

Tags: hard-drive, anti-virus, parallel-processing

I have 5 hard drives and am so very sick of waiting for 3 hours for the virus scanner to scan each drive one at a time.  I see absolutely no reason that a virus scanner can't be threaded to scan each drive separately and at the same time.  This would cut the scan process down immensely as half of a single core is being used the way it is doing it now, when I have 4 cores that can handle 8 threads.  There has to be some virus scanner that can do this.  From all research I've done, I really can't find a single one that is capable of this.

What I want is to be able to hit the "scan all drives" button and have it kick up 5 threads scanning all 5 drives at once in parallel.  Currently it starts with C then goes to D, E etc.  With a million files involved, this serial method takes a rediculous amount of time.  I know others have said that virus scanner companies just plain don't bother to do this because most people don't have multiple drives, so they see no point in taking the time to add the functionality.  Is there not at least one scanner out there that is designed for computers with multiple drives?

Furthermore, I do not care that it would take up a lot of computer resources.  I don't see why there can't at least be an option to use multiple threads (that can be turned off if you want to run something intensive in the foreground).

Comment: There are also some people who want to continue to use their computer while the AV software is scanning.

Comment: Which Av packages have you tried already?

Comment: Give Avast a try. Not exactly you're asking for, but it allows to create scanning jobs and start them simultaniously. You can assing each drive to each scanning job.

Comment: If the software supports command prompts, just pop open multiple prompts.  You can create a batch file to do this too.

Answer (score 3):

[Eset NOD 32](http://www.eset.com/us/) can do this. I just did a quick test and started up two scans:

[image]

I'm on my work laptop so it really started to slow down when started the second one.

Comment: If I were to spend money on AV software NOD32 would be the one.